# GET request is not working from Postman when i call spring rest api

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, postman

When i hit the curl localhost:3306/api/v1/requests with GET method to fetch the data from mysql database , postman throws that error.

> GET http://localhost:3306/api/v1/requests
> Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/
> Request Headers
> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
> Accept: */*
> Postman-Token: 867bb528-b3d6-410f-8c03-609ed49f3e90
> Host: localhost:3306
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Connection: keep-alive

Here is code from controller class
@Autowired
private RequestService rService;

```
//localhost:3306/request
@GetMapping("/requests")
public List<Request> getRequests(){
    return rService.getRequests();
}
```

Here is the code RequestService class

```
public interface RequestService {

    List<Request> getRequests();
}
```

Here is code from RequestServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class RequestServiceImpl implements RequestService{

    @Autowired
    private RequestRepository requestRepository;


        @Override
        public List<Request> getRequests() {
            return requestRepository.findAll();
        }
}
```

Comment: Port should be `8080` not `3306`. You call web server, not DB. `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/requests`

Comment: Ensure what  lucas-nguren mentioned , also , if your controller class is not in the same package as source package, you may need to either put them in same package or make use of @ComponentScan to scan your package ! I faced this issue couple of times

Comment: Thank you guys i really didn't see that..